# How to have Finder partial match?

Tags: macos, finder

In Finder, when I press letter keys, a file whose name **starts with** the keyword is selected. How can I make it partial match?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Exactly which keys do you press? Adding a screenshot to your post may also help explain the problem better.

Answer (score 2):

You can only get partial matches directly in a Finder window by using the search box at the top.

Let's say we're looking for iTunes…

Typing "itu" will go straight to it

[image]

Typing "tune" will not

[image]

Typing "tune" in the search box will reduce the selection to all files and file contents *which contain* the word partial "tune"

[image]

Clicking 'Name matches: tune' will then reduce that still further to only file names partially matching

[image]

Depending on exactly what you're searching, sometimes Spotlight is a better choice

[image]